How to remove duplicates from a list of dict based on some criteria?
I have the following list of dictionaries:
list_ = [{'printer': {'name': 'GEZHI, micro-printer', 'type': 'Usb', 'idVendor': 10473, 'idProduct': 649, 'in_ep': 129, 'out_ep': 1, 'filename': 'config1.yaml', 'status': 1}}, 
         {'printer': {'name': 'TECH, CLA58', 'type': 'Usb', 'idVendor': 26728, 'idProduct': 512, 'in_ep': 130, 'out_ep': 1, 'filename': 'config2.yaml', 'status': 0}}, 
         {'printer': {'name': 'GEZHI, micro-printer', 'type': 'Usb', 'idVendor': '10473', 'idProduct': '649', 'status': 2, 'out_ep': '1', 'in_ep': '129'}}]

How can I remove the duplicates based on only some dictionary keys: name, idVendor and idProduct?
I have tried based on name like the following, but I got an error:
res = [dict(t['printer']['name']) for t in {tuple(d.items()) for d['printer']['name'] in list_}]

NameError: name 'd' is not defined. Did you mean: 'id'?


{tuple(d.items()) for d['printer']['name'] in list_} alone has the same problem - think about it as an actual loop, what would for d['printer']['name'] in list_: do?

Is the duplicate check to be based on a single key at a time, or on the tuple of multiple keys simultaneously (meaning name, idVendor, and idProduct must all be identical to be considered a duplicate)?

The following function should do what you want:
def skip_duplicates(items: list[dict], key: str) -> list[dict]:
    """Skip duplicated items based on key provided."""

    existed: set[str | int] = set()
    items_: list[dict] = []

    for item in items:
        body = item["printer"]
        value = body[key]

        if value not in existed:
            items_.append(item)
            existed.add(value)
            
    return items_

If you would like to do the same based on multiple keys provided, you can do something like this:
def skip_duplicates(items: list[dict], keys: set[str]) -> list[dict]:
    """Skip duplicated items based on multiple keys provided."""

    existed: set[tuple[str | int]] = set()
    items_: list[dict] = []

    for item in items:
        body = item["printer"]
        values = tuple(body[key] for key in keys)

        if values not in existed:
            items_.append(item)
            existed.add(values)

    return items_


new_list = skip_duplicates(items=list_, keys={"name", "idVendor"})


you're not checking types. ids can be int or str

Create a dict where the keys are tuples containing the values you want to consider when checking for duplicates, and the values are the dictionaries in the original list.
The keys in a dict are unique, and each will only have one corresponding dictionary.
Your example data has mixed types (e.g., idProduct values as int 649 and str '649'). Convert the values in the tuple keys to str to treat them as duplicates regardless of type, or remove the conversion to str if you want to treat them as different.
keys = ["name", "idVendor", "idProduct"]
unique = {tuple(str(e["printer"].get(key, "")) for key in keys): e for e in list_}
list_ = list(unique.values())

[
    {
        "printer": {
            "name": "GEZHI, micro-printer",
            "type": "Usb",
            "idVendor": "10473",
            "idProduct": "649",
            "status": 2,
            "out_ep": "1",
            "in_ep": "129",
        }
    },
    {
        "printer": {
            "name": "TECH, CLA58",
            "type": "Usb",
            "idVendor": 26728,
            "idProduct": 512,
            "in_ep": 130,
            "out_ep": 1,
            "filename": "config2.yaml",
            "status": 0,
        }
    },
]


Try this:
list_ = [{'printer': {'name': 'GEZHI, micro-printer', 'type': 'Usb', 'idVendor': 10473, 'idProduct': 649, 'in_ep': 129, 'out_ep': 1, 'filename': 'config1.yaml', 'status': 1}}, 
         {'printer': {'name': 'TECH, CLA58', 'type': 'Usb', 'idVendor': 26728, 'idProduct': 512, 'in_ep': 130, 'out_ep': 1, 'filename': 'config2.yaml', 'status': 0}}, 
         {'printer': {'name': 'GEZHI, micro-printer', 'type': 'Usb', 'idVendor': '10473', 'idProduct': '649', 'status': 2, 'out_ep': '1', 'in_ep': '129'}}]

def skip_duplicates(data):
    new = []
    ok = True
    for printer in data:
        for printer2 in new:
            if ( printer['printer']['name'] == printer2['printer']['name']) or int(printer['printer']['idVendor']) == int(printer2['printer']['idVendor']) or (int(printer['printer']['idProduct']) == int(printer2['printer']['idProduct'])):
                ok = False
        if ok == True:
            new.append(printer)
        ok = True
    return new
print(skip_duplicates(list_))

This will make a filtered list of unique printers.
A printer is unique if there are no other printers with the same name, idVendor or idProduct.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
